# What does mean java source/binary format?

Tags: java, netbeans

What does mean source/binary format in java? what is it?

This property appears in netbeans project's properties/source category.

Comment: Binary is the compiled code found in the /bin/ folder, source is the code you type in the /src/ folder, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 6):

Means if you're working with a project that must be compatible with JDK 7, 6, 5 ...
so that the IDE can recognize unsupported features in your code.

The IDE would compile with the appropiate `-source` and `-target` options.

Comment: See here, for the mentioned options: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options

Answer (score 0):

I don't use NetBeans, but I 'd guess it represents Java compiler version settings -- certain versions activate language features (1.5 activates generics, for example) and reduce backward compatibility.